# Catel DataWindow OK button does not close view

Tags: catel

I have a DataWindow (MyWindow) with the OK Cancel and Apply buttons. Within this DataWindow is a View (MyView). For both MyWindow and MyView I have overridden GetViewModelType() like so:

```
protected override Type GetViewModelType()
        {
            return typeof(MyViewModel);
        }
```

I also have MyViewModel registered with MyWindow via the UIVisualizerService:

```
_uiVisualizerService.Register(typeof(MyViewModel), typeof(MyWindow));
```

On MyViewModel I have overridden ViewModelBase.Save():

```
protected override bool Save()
{
    if (HasErrors)
        return false;

    MyModel.SaveChanges();

    return base.Save();
}
```

I use this to display MyWindow:

```
var myViewModel = TypeFactory.Default.CreateInstanceWithParametersAndAutoCompletion<MyViewModel>();
            _uiVisualizerService.Show(myViewModel);
```

But when I click on the 'OK' Button of MyWindow, although the Save() method is called and base.Save() returns 'true', the Window is not closed.

If I open the MyWindow using,

```
new MyWindow().ShowDialog();
```

the 'OK' button works.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? The Apply and Cancel Buttons work 100%

**EDIT:**
I just noticed something, using `Show()` does not close the window when OK is clicked (as said above) BUT `ShowDialog()` does.

Is this correct?

Comment: If you think you found a bug, please raise a ticket in the official issue tracker: http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker

Comment: Hi Geert. I have loaded an issue as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was fixed by updating to Catel v4.0.